# list all rows (id,name) of a model as a dropdownlist for particular column in another model

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii, html-select

The thing is all I need is list all rows(id,name) of a model1  as a dropdownlist for a particular column in model2 stored is id in db but display names in dropdownlist at user interface.

Can I do something like write a function in model2 and call the function in controller2/create will it work I am not sure for it

Please let me know if I can achieve it in any good way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a function in your MODEL2 Like

```
public function myDropDownData(){
 $data = Model1::model()->findAll();
 $datalist = CHtml::listData($data, 'id', 'name');
 retrun $datalist;
}
```

use in view like this

```
echo $form->dropDownList($model2,'model2_column_name',$model2->myDropDownData());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CHtml::listData()** for it like

```
    CHtml::dropDownList('myDropDown', '', CHtml::listData(Model1::model()->findAll(),
'id', 'name'));
```

Then you can **access the value** as
 `$_POST['myDropDown'];`